# Spring command object discrimination

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

How to i can discriminate command objects in spring-mvc Controller? For example, i have following bean-classes used as form object:

```
public class CreateServiceFormBean {
    @NotBlank
    @Length(min = 3, max = 120)
    private String name;
}
public class CreateDependedServiceFormBean extends CreateServiceFormBean {
    @NotNull
    private Short parentServiceId;
}
```

Getter's and Setter's is cutted out.

```
@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String createService(CreateServiceFormBean form) {
        if (form instanceof CreateServiceFormBean) {
            System.out.println("create Service");
            //new ServiceEntity(form.getName())
        } else if (form instanceof CreateDependedServiceFormBean)  {
            System.out.println("create depended Service");
            parentService = ... get parent service entity...
            //new DependedServiceEntity(form.getName(), parentService)
        }
        return null;
}
```

How do this? I think about create abstract controller for this two dto's, but is not elegant..maybe can handled in one method..
And how to correct get parent service entity? Some like method ModelAttribute annotation whose return entity by id?

Thanks for Replies!

Comment: what is discriminate command objects

Comment: For example(in form html): <input type="hidden" name="OBJECT_CLASS_WHAT_I_RECIEVE_AS_ARGUMENT" value="CreateDependedServiceFormBean" />

Comment: public String createService(@Annotation:IWantOneOfThisObjects(CreateServiceFormBean.class, CreateDependedServiceFormBean.class) CreateServiceFormBean form) {
maybe as this...